# Unable to dismiss progress dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

Here is my code segment I am trying to dismiss dialog but it is not getting dismissed and also i don't get any error on logcat.Please correct me where i am wrong ?

All the Log.v statement get executed.Even log.v statement after `pd.dismiss() (Log.v("TAG","progress dismiss");)` gets printed.

Please point my mistake or suggest some alternative way to dismiss the progressdialog.

```
 btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //do something
                        } else {
                            Log.v("TAG","above progressDialog");
                            final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ChangePassword.this);
                            ProgressDialog.show(ChangePassword.this, "", "Loading...", false, true);
                            new Thread() {
                                public void run() {
                                    try {                               
                                        sleep(2000);
                                        Log.v("TAG","in try block");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                    // dismiss the progress dialog
                                    pd.dismiss();
    //                              Log.v("TAG","progress dismiss");
                                }
                            }.start();
                            Log.v("TAG","after start");


                             public void run()
                             {
                                 try{

                                     if (!(txtOldPass.getText().toString())
                                            .equals(SetGetValues.getPassword())) {

                                        Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this,
                                                "Invalid Old Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                .show();
                                        txtOldPass.setText("");
                                        txtNewPass.setText("");
                                        txtCnfPass.setText("");
                                    } else {
                                        if (!(txtNewPass.getText().toString())
                                                .equals(txtCnfPass.getText().toString())) {
                                            Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this,
                                                    "Re-Enter New Password",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            txtOldPass.setText("");
                                            txtNewPass.setText("");
                                            txtCnfPass.setText("");
                                        } else {
                                            try {

    handler = new Handler();
                         handler.postDelayed(new Thread (new Runnable(){
                                                JSONStringer loginuser = new JSONStringer()
                                                        .object()
                                                        .key("userid")
                                                        .value(SetGetValues.getUserid()
                                                                .trim())
                                                        .key("password")
                                                        .value(txtCnfPass.getText()
                                                                .toString().trim())
                                                        .key("oldpassword")
                                                        .value(txtOldPass.getText()
                                                                .toString().trim())
                                                        .endObject();
                                                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(
                                                        loginuser.toString());
                                                JSONObject results = bc
                                                        .returnJSONObject(loginuser,
                                                                "url");

                                                String message = results
                                                        .getString("message");
                                                String isvalid = results
                                                        .getString("isvalid");
                                                if (isvalid.contains("FALSE")) {
                                                } else {
                                                    //pd.dismiss();
                                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                            ChangePassword.this,
                                                            "Password changed successfully",
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                 //TODO: handle exception
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                             }catch(Exception e)
                             {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }
                             }
                            }), 1000);


                        }
                    }

                });
```

Comment: dear what are you trying to implement exactly? Webservice call, database operation or else?

Comment: @Paresh Mayani : I was trying to show progress dialog while i call the webservices.

Comment: Thank you everybody for giving me response

Comment: just a quick suggestion: As you want to implement webservice call or any long running task in background, during that also want to show progress bar then AsyncTask is the best concept to implement. For more info of the same, check this example:http://goo.gl/ntYJd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not dismissing the same ProgressDialog that you are showing. Replace this:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ChangePassword.this);
ProgressDialog.show(ChangePassword.this, "", "Loading...", false, true);
```

with this:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(ChangePassword.this, "", "Loading...", false, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (pd.isShowing()) {
             pd.dismiss();
   }
```

Instead of using thread Use Async Task
[usage](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html)

Answer (score 1):

You problem probably is, that you're trying to modify the UI (dismiss the dialog) from another thread. I'm surprised that you don't get an error message. Try dismissing the dialog from the UI thread, for example by using [.runOnUIThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to use element of `UI` Thread `progressDialog` in a non UI thread .
This will be allowed through `AsyncTask` , `handler` or `RunOnUIThread(runnable)` only .

read more about them and use any one .